# /hello Not Found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I create a project using Spring Initializer.

I added a mapping for /hello:

```
package com.propfinancing.www;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class PfWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PfWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
      return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

I created a war file and uploaded that to my tomcat server.
When I go to the URL http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/hello

I get a 404 - Not Found page.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: your url is going to be at local host not that propfinancing one youre referring. Should look something like this: http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: Localhost is not where I am running the app.  I uploaded the war file to a Tomcat server.

Comment: As a test, I ssh'd into the remote server and typed this command:
lynx http://localhost:8080/www/hello

I still get a 404 page with the message The requested resource [/www/hello] is not available

Comment: lynx http://localhost:8080/hello also gives me a 404 page

Comment: Can you confirm that the app is running? Is the 404 page a Spring Boot white label or custom error page? See https://zetcode.com/springboot/whitelabelerror/ for information on error pages.

Comment: Did you try on local first before deploying to server. Debugging on local should help.

Comment: Are you certain that you have the servlet context correct, e.g. is your app context for sure www?

Comment: @JoshVandeWalle: The 404 page says Apache Tomcat on the bottom, you can visit http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/hello to see it for yourself.

Comment: @SKR: I tried it locally on the server using lynx and it has the same behavior.  I don't know how to debug it any further.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @lane.maxwell: I put a test.html file in the webapp directory and the loaded it via the URL http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/test.html and it loaded the page correctly so, yes, www is the correct app context.

Comment: Maybe try creating a seperate class with restcontroller annotation instead of putting it on same springbootapplication class

Comment: @SKR I created this class:
`code`
package com.propfinancing.www;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

public class TestController {
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public String test() {
    return String.format("Testing");
  }
}
`code`

When I go to http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/test I still get a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.
Apparently, Spring 5 does not work with tomcat 10:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22414

I am going to install Tomcat 9 on my server and see if that works.

Comment: I found a better answer.  Following the guide on this page [https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/deploy-a-spring-boot-rest-app-as-a-war-to-tomcat-10/](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/deploy-a-spring-boot-rest-app-as-a-war-to-tomcat-10/) I placed my war file in webapps-javaee and everything works perfectly!